# How to use .map() to iterate an object and create number of <Item />

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created an object with label and value keys. Now What I want to do is create  for each item in the object by using .map() function.

```
// my object
const ageData = [...Array(71)].map((x, i) => ({ label: i + 10, value: i + 10 }));
//My object looks like 0: {label: 10, value: 10} 1: {label: 11, value: 11}

//What I want to create
<Item label=10 value=10 />
<Item label=11 value=11 />

//My current non-working solution
ageData.map(obj => <Item label=obj.label value=obj.value />)
```

Comment: That's the correct approach, just use valid JSX syntax.

Comment: as @jonrsharpe mentioned use the correct JSX {} and don't forget key attribute

Comment: Is this the right approach? ageData2.map(obj => <Item key={obj.index} label={obj.label} value={obj.value} />)

Comment: @sinan ...does it *work*?

Comment: Nope it says cant find variable obj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenters mentioned above the syntax needs a bit work. It could be something like this using a functional component:

```
const Items = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.someArray.map(obj => (<Item label={obj.label} value={obj.value} />))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then return the following from a functional component, or your render method, where you want to display the items:

```
<Items someArray={ageData} />
```

Where ageDate is your array.

Note that you were missing the `{}` around your expressions inside the JSX code, as well as parentheses around the JSX expression your were returning from your map.

### Bonus:

You can write your functional component shorter like this, if you just need it to return an expression like above:

```
const Items = props => (
  <div>
    {props.someArray.map(obj => (<Item label={obj.label} value={obj.value} />))}
  </div>
)
```